# Python Numpy Question and Python Version Question

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, matrix-multiplication, norm

I want to use Numpy with Python 3.2 and it won't work; it says I need 3.1. Does anyone know how to get around this issue, other than using 3.1? What do I have to import in order to make this work in a python program?

I want to represent a matrix in python, as well as get the norm of the matrix. How would I go about doing this with Numpy? Is that inside Numpy or Python? What about Matrix multiplication? Also, this matrix is actually a vector with x and y as its variables.

The final question. Some members on here feel that using Python 3.2 is not the best way to create a professional product, even though on Python.org, they specifically state that using 3.2 or 2.7 are the most stable versions available today. Am I wrong here? If I am, what version of Python should I use? Thanks in advance.

Also, I don't have enough rep to post three individual questions, so If you can answer a part, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should post these as three distinct questions.

Comment: You think so? Is it too much?

Comment: It seems fine as one question to me.

Comment: fixed it but I don't have enough rep to post the other two.

Comment: welll, I change it again....ugh

Comment: When I said it looked fine as one question only the first paragraph was showing.  Now that I see the whole thing I agree with TheChes44, it should be separate questions.

Comment: well, read the last paragraph. lol.I dont have enough rep, and I kinda need an answer on this cause I have a short amount of time to crunch out a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NumPy 1.6.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.6.0/) released on 5/14/2011 supports Python 3.2.  The prior version (1.5.1) was released prior to Python 3.2.  So what version of NumPy are you using?  If it's 1.6.0 and it's not working on 3.2 it might be a bug with NumPy and you should report it to NumPy.

Regarding basic use of `numpy`, use [this tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html).  I can see that it covers array creation and multiplication fairly early on.  Regarding norms, see [this reference page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).

Regarding whether to use Python 2.7 or 3.2, there's [a page at python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) that discusses this in detail.

Comment: I found it! Thanks. When I initially searched for it,I couldn't find 1.6.Now it works. Do you know how to use it?

Comment: Thanks dude. Well I am not using any of those libraries, I am just using Numpy. I mean, I am using threads also, but that is about the same in 2.7 and 3.2 right?

Comment: Yes, threads in 2.7 and 3.2 are almost exactly the same.  An environment you don't control is one that you can't install software on, like a webserver or a locked down office pc.

Comment: Oh, well, I dont have that problem, then. It will be fine to run 3.2. Thanks for the help it has been appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider looking at the numpy documentation and the tutorials to familiarize yourself with how it works:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/

[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html)

The documentation includes a lot of examples on a per function basis, so for example if you wanted to find how to take the norm, take a look at

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html